# "InvalidDataContractException: Type contains two members with same data member name" for no apparent reason

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, datacontractserializer, datacontract

I have the following types:

Base type:

```
   [DataContract(Name = "protectedFile", Namespace = Constants.ManagementNamespace)]
    public class ProtectedFile
    {
        public ProtectedFile(string virtualDiskName, FileIdInfo fileIdInfo)
        {
            VirtualDiskName = virtualDiskName;
            FileIdInfo = fileIdInfo;
        }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets file id information
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Name = "fileIdInfo")]
    public FileIdInfo FileIdInfo { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets Virtual Disk Name
    /// </summary>
    [DataMember(Name = "virtualDiskName")]
    public string VirtualDiskName { get; set; }

      // .. Equality members

    }
```

ProtectedFile contains types:

```
    [Serializable]
    [DataContract(Name = "FileIdInfo", Namespace = Constants.ManagementNamespace)]
    public sealed class FileIdInfo
    {
        public FileIdInfo()
        {
        }

        public FileIdInfo(FileSystemFileIdInformation fsFileId, int driverFileId)
        {
            DriverFileId = driverFileId;
            FsFileId = fsFileId;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets file system file id information
        /// </summary>
        [DataMember(Name = "fsFileId")]
        public FileSystemFileIdInformation FsFileId { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets driver file id information
        /// </summary>
        [DataMember(Name = "driverFileId")]
        public int DriverFileId { get; set; }

        // .. Equality members
    }


    [Serializable]
    [DataContract(Name = "FileSystemFileIdInformation", Namespace = Constants.ManagementNamespace)]
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct FileSystemFileIdInformation
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "VolumeSerialNumber")]
        private readonly ulong _volumeSerialNumber;

        [DataMember(Name = "FileId")]
        private readonly FileId128 _fileId;

        public ulong VolumeSerialNumber
        {
            get { return _volumeSerialNumber; }
        }

        public FileId128 FileId
        {
            get { return _fileId; }
        }

        // .. Equality members
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// File Identifier inside the volume (FILE_ID_128 at ntifs.h/winnt.h)
    /// </summary>
    [Serializable]
    [DataContract(Name = "FileId128", Namespace = Constants.ManagementNamespace)]
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct FileId128
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "highPart")]
        private readonly ulong _highPart;

        [DataMember(Name = "lowPart")]
        private readonly ulong _lowPart;

        public ulong HighPart
        {
            get { return _highPart; }
        }

        public ulong LowPart
        {
            get { return _lowPart; }
        }

        // .. Equality members
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Internal file system file id - AAFILE_ID_INFORMATION from AAFileFilterCommon.h
    /// </summary>
    [Serializable]
    [DataContract(Name = "FileSystemFileIdInformation", Namespace = Constants.ManagementNamespace)]
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct FileSystemFileIdInformation
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "VolumeSerialNumber")]
        private readonly ulong _volumeSerialNumber;

        [DataMember(Name = "FileId")]
        private readonly FileId128 _fileId;

        public ulong VolumeSerialNumber
        {
            get { return _volumeSerialNumber; }
        }

        public FileId128 FileId
        {
            get { return _fileId; }
        }

        // .. Equality members
    }
```

All looks good, every data contract member has a unique name but I get a serialization exception

```
InvalidDataContractException: 
FileIdInfo type contains two members FsFileId and DriverFileId with same 
data member name fsFileId
```

But I have only one member with that name. The only unusal thing is that I'm using structures as data members, but that is supported.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce this, just in case - you copied 2 times *FileSystemFileIdInformation* structure at

> ProtectedFile contains types:

I wrote simple serialization example and it works without any exceptions in both ways(seriaization and deserialization) - my only change is that I added constructors for readonly parameters, but it really doesn't matter for serialization.

```
var protectedFile=
new ProtectedFile("C",new FileIdInfo(new FileSystemFileIdInformation(
                        1, new FileId128(2,3)),
                4));
            DataContractSerializer d = new DataContractSerializer(protectedFile.GetType());
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            d.WriteObject(stream, protectedFile);
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            var fileAfterSerialization = d.ReadObject(stream);
```